# Count 10 most frequent words using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, text

I want to write a PySpark snippet of code that first reads some data in the form of a text file from a Cloud Storage bucket. The text file contains paragraphs of text separated by newline characters, words are also separated
using space characters.

I need to calculate the 10 highest-frequency words in the given text file.

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from google.cloud import storage
import sys
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("some paragraph")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

bucket_name = (sys.argv[1])
destination_blob_name = (sys.argv[2])

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
 
downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
print(downloaded_blob)


print(blob)
def words():
    alist = {}
    for line in blob:
        fields = line.split("|")
        print(fields)
        movies[int(fields[0])]=fields[1]
    return movies

myline = words()
myRDD = sc.parallelize([myline])

print(myRDD.collect())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had a file like this:

```py
s = """a b c d e f g h i j
a a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p"""
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

You could get top 10 words with counts into a Python dictionary like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

split_on_spaces = F.split('value', ' ')
df = (
    spark.read.text('file.txt')
    .withColumn('value', F.explode(split_on_spaces))
    .groupBy('value').count()
    .orderBy(F.desc('count'))
)
top_val_dict = {r['value']:r['count'] for r in df.head(10)}

print(top_val_dict)
# {'a': 3, 'g': 2, 'e': 2, 'f': 2, 'i': 2, 'h': 2, 'd': 2, 'c': 2, 'j': 2, 'b': 2}
```

This only assumes your case you described where words are separated with spaces. In the real world scenario, you will probably need to deal with punctuation, potential removal of non-words after punctuation removal, etc. That is up to you to further tweak the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use RDD transformations, you can use `collections.Counter()` to create frequencies and then sort it based on the counts.

here's an example to get top 3

```py
from collections import Counter

data_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile('file.txt')

data_rdd.collect()
# ['a b c b a d h t t a w b c c c']

data_rdd. \
    map(lambda x: x.split(' ')). \
    map(lambda e: sorted(Counter(e).items(), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)). \
    flatMap(lambda e: e[:3]). \
    collect()
# [('c', 4), ('a', 3), ('b', 3)]
```

a real world example with 3 paragraphs separated by `\n` and words separated by  .

```py
txt = """foo bar bar baz bar\nbaz baz foo foo baz\nunfoo unbaz unbar"""

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)

# read file as text file
data_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile('file.txt')
# spark automatically splits paragraphs
# ['foo bar bar baz bar', 'baz baz foo foo baz', 'unfoo unbaz unbar']

from collections import Counter

# get top 3 words in the text file
data_rdd. \
    map(lambda x: x.split(' ')). \
    flatMap(lambda x: Counter(x).items()). \
    reduceByKey(lambda c1, c2: c1 + c2). \
    top(3, key=lambda k: k[1])
# [('baz', 4), ('foo', 3), ('bar', 3)]
```

if you want all words along with their frequencies, you can sort the words based on frequencies and simply collect

```py
data_rdd. \
    map(lambda x: x.split(' ')). \
    flatMap(lambda x: Counter(x).items()). \
    reduceByKey(lambda c1, c2: c1 + c2). \
    sortBy(lambda x: x[1], False). \
    collect()

# [('baz', 4), ('foo', 3), ('bar', 3), ('unfoo', 1), ('unbar', 1), ('unbaz', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

##### To find 1 Most Frequent words using PySpark

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from google.cloud import storage
import sys
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("some paragraph")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

bucket_name = (sys.argv[1])
destination_blob_name = (sys.argv[2])

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
 
downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
print(downloaded_blob)
# to generate the word counts of each words in text file 
wordCounts = downloaded_blob.flatMap(lambda line: line.split())
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1))
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
# to get 1 most frequent word 
wordCounts.reduce(lambda a, b: a if (a[1] > b[1]) else b)
```